# Solr & Nutch - Indexing only certain urls

Tags: solr, nutch

I'm using nutch 1.6 for crawling, and solr 3.6.2 for indexing the urls crawled.
But, I want to keep only urls containing `details`.
What I have done is to add many (a lot of) filters to `nutch/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt`.

I want to know if there is a better solution even if I should crawl all data (urls), and then filter only the important once in Solr (in `Solrindex` command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the pages, it would be best to filter out from the indexing itself.
However, If you have a pattern that you can filter upon in Solr, you can use [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to do the filtering.

Comment: if you don't have a filter pattern you need to filter at nutch level. If you have if you just index all the pages and have it filtered at Solr. The other question is would you ever need these pages ? if not then why index them ?

Comment: I dont need them how can I index only relevent pages.

Comment: Adding it to the regex urlfilter is the only way and you can use regex patterns as well here

Comment: that's what I have done.  I guess that there no way to index only a set of urls.